# Pragmatically Save excel to SharePoint list

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am working with a very limited infrastructure and need to come up with many workarounds 
For a recent project I need to parse data from and xls file (not a real excel but a html table with the extension changed to xls from the source) and save it to a SharePoint list so I can use the SP rest API to access the data.

Anyone tried to achieve something similar?

Comment: Which part are you stuck with? Parsing the HTML (if it's really HTML, don't bother considering anything relating to Excel here, the file extension is irrelevant to the file contents) and extracting information can be done with free libraries which you can find online. Then there's the business of uploading to Sharepoint. Again I'm sure you can find examples of that part online. Did you research or try anything before posting? What is giving you a problem? We'll happily fix your code if you have any, but until that point it's up to you to do some research, we are not a human search engine.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Sorry if the question is a bit vague let me explain what I currently have and maybe also edit that in the main question, I am currently able to parse the file with ACE.OLDB and expose it as an API using MVC, however I recently learned that I wont be able to use that, the workaround I thought of is the SharePoint list, however the results I am finding are quire confusing.

Comment: " I recently learned that I wont be able to use that,". Why, exactly? What's wrong with it? And how does that relate to Sharepoint? And " the results I am finding are quire confusing". What results? What is confusing?

Comment: Because of Infrastructure limitation I am unable to get a host for the Owin module, so my reasoning was to ditch it and replace the API part. By saving the data in a SP list I would be able to use SP restful API instead to load the data from a JS client.

Comment: so really is the question simply "how do I add a file to a SharePoint list?" ? . Or is there another problem? What have you tried or researched in relation to this?

Comment: I dn't need to add the file but rather parse its content automatically as soon as it update and update the list with new values, the second solution I was thinking about is to save the data in a JSON file and upload it to SP but I am not sure how well java-script would handle that using get requests

Comment: JavaScript loves JSON (it is JavaScript Object Notation, after all).

Comment: Indeed, What I did in the end was totally different, Had my engine sitting in a virtual machine parsing the HTML and publishing a JSON file with a .txt extension to SP, probably too many workarounds but it works great with Ajax calls and that's all I needed